# Overwriting a non-text file with another

Tags: java, sqlite, file-writing

I am not sure how to overwrite non-text files. How can I overwrite my main.db file (sqlite 3) with my default.db file?

```
private void yesAction() {

    try {

        String text = Files.readString(Paths.get("src\\main\\database\\default.db"));

        System.out.println(text);

        Files.writeString(Paths.get("src\\main\\database\\main.db"), text, Charset.defaultCharset());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite db files or any other file using this FileChannel.

```
try {
    File oldDb = new File(old, oldDbPath);
    File newDb = new File(new, newDbPath);

    if (newDb.exists()) {
        FileChannel oldDbChannel = new FileInputStream(oldDb).getChannel();
        FileChannel newDbChannel = new FileOutputStream(newDb).getChannel();
        newDbChannel.transferFrom(oldDbChannel, 0, oldDbChannel.size());
        oldDbChannel.close();
        newDbChannel.close();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can read more about FileChannel here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.